Is geometryA.intersections(geometryB) the same like geometryB.intersections(geometryA)?
I have two geometries(polygons) and use the intersection function of the geometries to get the intersection geometry with geotools.
The result surprised me - why:

polygonA.intersection(polygonB) - throw an exception
polygonB.intersection(polygonA) - get an valid geometry

When I do the same with PostGis, I get in both cases a valid geometry:
It should be no difference between polygonA.intersection(polygonB) or polygonB.intersection(polygonA). The result should be the same.
I use geotools in Version 31.0. It that a bug or understand the method intersection not correct.

If that is the actual spelling of the variable names, then yes an error would certainly have to be expected...

Go on give us a clue - what is the exception? where is an actual example code we can run?

Please check for the typo "polyong"

If this turns out to be just because of a typo, please close the question. If not, please provide detailed error logs.
